# passing _this into an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So I'm not sure what the best way to do this is, currently I have an ajax call that looks some like this

```
var _this = this;

        _.each(this.models, function (model) {

            model.fetch({
                success: function(model, response) {
                    if (_.has(model.attributes, "settings")) {                            
                            _this.populateSettings(_this);
                        }
                    }
```

In the populateSettings method, I need certain attributes on this Backbone view.  I wasn't sure how to get those attributes except to pass in each specific attribute, or pass in a reference to this backbone view and in populateSettings, use that reference to populate the view.  Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to listen for `sync` events on `model` in your view, so that whenever `model` successfully syncs with the data from the server, your view could run `populateSettings`.

This could look something like this:

```
model.on('sync', this.populateSettings, this)
```

Note the third argument, `this`. Passing `this` as the third argument sets the context in which the event handler will run. From the [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) docs:

> To supply a context value for this when the callback is invoked, pass the optional third argument: `model.on('change', this.render, this)`

If you used an event listener like this, you could remove the `success:` option altogether. And you may also find the `change` or `change:[attribute]` events useful as well.